# Training A Neural Net in R and getting "Error in if (reached.threshold < min.reached.threshold) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r, neural-network, model.matrix

I am trying to train a neural network in R using the `neuralnet` package. I am running a regression model and trying to predict a count variable "Rented_Bike_Count". I have a mixture of categorical and numeric variables and have made dummy variables for the categorical variables via `model.matrix`.

I have turned my data into a model.matrix and removed the intercept term. I have read similar questions to this issue and everyone says to decrease the learning rate. It doesn't seem to help at all and I don't believe I need to make my learning rate as small as `1e-6`.

What else could be the issue? How can I get around this? I tried using `threshold=0.5` and it seems to work but I don't really understand why.

Code:

```
library(caret)
library(neuralnet) 

sigmoid <-  function(x) 1 / (1+exp(-x)) 

# must make our factor variables in to a one-hot encoding (binary form)
X_train <- model.matrix(~., data = Train_set_standardized)[,-1] # remove intercept term

dimnames(X_train)
Train_nn_sigmoid <- neuralnet(Rented_Bike_Count~., 
                     data = X_train, 
                     hidden = 1, 
                     learningrate = 1e-6, 
                     act.fct = sigmoid,
                     linear.output = TRUE, # FALSE Means output node gets the activation function
                     threshold = 0.5,
                     err.fct = "sse") 

Error in if (reached.threshold < min.reached.threshold) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: can you provide a bit more information, what is the dependent variable ```Rented_Bike_Count``` ? Are you doing classification or regression? You get that error because the err function is not specified correctly

Comment: Sorry. It is a continuous variable (count) and I am performing regression. I still get the same error if I specify ```err.fact = "sse"```

Comment: sigmoid functions cannot be used for regression.. you can use either logistic or other functions

Comment: @StupidWolf I am using it as a hidden layer activation function not as a classification in the output layer since I set ```linear.output = TRUE```. Is setting act.fct = "logistic" that different than using my own sigmoid definition? Sigmoid is a special case of the logistic function after all.

Comment: Ok yes most probably.. sorry about bed time. did you scale your data?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you did not scale the data. Using an example:

```
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)

X_train = model.matrix(~.,data=BostonHousing)[,-1]

m <- neuralnet(medv ~. , data = X_train, 
                      hidden = c(5,3), 
                      learningrate = 1e-6, 
                      linear.output = TRUE, 
                      threshold = 0.5,
                      act.fct=sigmoid,
                      err.fct = "sse")

Error in while (step < stepmax && reached.threshold > threshold) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

See this [post about scaling the data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421927/neural-networks-input-data-normalization-and-centering). I am sure there are other posts if you search. If you scale it:

```
X_scaled = scale(X_train)
X_scaled = data.frame(X_scaled)

m <- neuralnet(medv ~. , data = X_scaled, 
                      hidden = c(5,3), 
                      learningrate = 1e-6, 
                      linear.output = TRUE, 
                      threshold = 0.5,
                      act.fct=sigmoid,
                      err.fct = "sse")

plot(predict(m,X_scaled),X_scaled$medv)
```

[image]

Comment: My data is scaled and centered. I applied z-score normalization to my numeric variables. Do I really need to scale my binary dummy variables as well?

Comment: no... you don't need to.. ok the error comes about because you get some nonsense values as predictions... I am really not so sure now.. what's the issue

Comment: Yeah, I am stumped. It works sometimes if I change the ```threshold``` but I cannot understand why. I have trained many networks in Python but I am trying to see how they work a bit in R as well.

Comment: I changed my ```learningrate``` to ```1e-10``` and am doing only a small number of hidden and now I am getting pretty good results... I don't know why my data needs such a small learning rate. I've never seen a learning rate that small before